# Redis and DB communication

Tags: java, sql, database, architecture, redis

I am developing a photo album system and decided to use Redis. I keep the user's photo data, (who has which photos) in Redis. For example : photos:1000:pid [1,24,525,12,42,62,56] means the user with the id 1000 has the photos in the list (ids). The point that I confused is when I got the [1,24,525,12,42,62,56], how I can get the photo details ? I thought using Redis to get photo details again. However, when a user has 150 photo, getting them one by one (from java using jedis in a loop) costs 100 - 150 msec which is not suitable for my case. I have to manage a high traffic. Response shouldn't be over 100msec.

I decided to use DB by using stored procedures, "one shot, get everything" knowing the photo ids (they are indexed). Does "Get ids from Redis, get details from DB" is a proper approach ? What would you do for this situation ?

Comment: What's the problem putting all the details in redis, in keys with type _hash_ ?

Comment: Redis has no search feature. can I say like "select * from photos where ownerid=1000" to get specific photo set with all needed fields ?

Comment: That's not how you do it. You create multiple keys with multiple purposes. For example, one key holds all photos for a given owner. Then another keys hold the details of each specific photo.

Comment: So I got 100 photo ids from, lets say,  user:1000:photos key which keeps all photo ids of the user. How can I get those 100 photo details from, lets say, photos:<photoid>:dtls hash ? I have to run this 100 times for each photo id right? This is my major problem that I mentioned in my question.

Answer (score 2):

I would not recommend to use two different stores. Keep it simple. Think about the consistency of your data. If you are more familiar with a relational database, there is nothing wrong in using it (for all your data).

Now, if you want to store everything in Redis, it is also possible, provided you can anticipate all access paths to your data.

With Redis, running several commands to get some data is quite efficient if you bundle these commands in the same rountrip. Redis server (and most clients) fully supports [pipelining](http://redis.io/topics/pipelining). Assuming you use Jedis, you can find some examples [here](https://github.com/xetorthio/jedis/blob/master/src/test/java/redis/clients/jedis/tests/PipeliningTest.java).

Actually, there are multiple ways to solve your problem.

Let's suppose you have the following model:

```
photos:<userid> -> set of photo IDs for a given user ID
photo:<photoid> -> hash of photo properties for a give photo ID
```

If you are interested by retrieving specific photo properties (say name and size) for a given user (i.e. like a select name, size from ...), it can be done using a single SORT command.

```
 SORT photos:<userid> by nosort get # get photo:*->name photo:*->size
```

If you are interested by retrieving **all** the photo properties for a given user (i.e. like a select * from ...), it is a bit more complex.

One solution is to use pipelining and perform two roundtrips:

- first roundtrip to get the set of photo IDs (using SMEMBERS)
- second roundtrip to pipeline all the HGETALL commands (one per photo)

An alternative solution would be to use [server-side Lua scripting](http://redis.io/commands/eval) to perform all the aggregation on server side. Complexity is higher, but the cost would be a single roundtrip.